# Gradle disable task

Tags: gradle

Can I disable the task, only for one task?
For example

```
flywayMigrate {
    doFirst {
        gradle.startParameter.excludedTaskNames += "test"
//      test.enabled = false
    }
    dependsOn flywayClean
    dependsOn build
}
```

I want you to do **flywayMigrate**
The tests were turned off.

But when I run **clean build** tests were run also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with the task graph of the build as follows:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph -> 
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(flywayMigrate)) {
        test.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Here is a closure executed then the task graoh is built, just before task are configured or executed. It check's whether `flywayMigrate` task will be executed and if yes, it disables `test` task.

[Here is](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#configure-by-dag) how it's described in the official docs.